# Getting this scroll next to the heading in hero Section of portfolio website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't wrap my head around how this is happening, neither have I ever seen this before.
Please Help Kind Souls of StackOverFlow!!
[Here is a picture of Whatsup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Mo8.png)

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my phone at the moment, but from your screenshot, my guess is that the element that the heading is in, whether it be a div, h1, or other has a set height. My suggestion is to add the below styles to the heading’s element:

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden; // if all else fails, this will hide the scroll-bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after lots of head-scratching. I found out this was being caused because of adding bootstrap 5 to the website, mainly bootstraps font was causing it. Why? That is still unknown

Comment: Can you share a link to this so I can inspect it and then adjust my answer accordingly?

Comment: I just made the github repo, the project is nowhere near finish. The thing in question is the div with class "heroy". I have temporarily fixed it with overflow hidden. But once you disable that, the problem comes back and goes away once you remove bootstrap.  https://github.com/dootrex/portfolio